# Get String (Text) before next upper letter

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

I have the following:

```
string test = "CustomerNumber";
```

or

```
string test2 = "CustomerNumberHello";
```

the result should be:

```
string result = "Customer";
```

The first word from the string is the result, the first word goes until the first uppercase letter, here 'N'

I already tried some things like this:

```
var result = string.Concat(s.Select(c => char.IsUpper(c) ? " " + c.ToString() : c.ToString()))
    .TrimStart();
```

But without success, hope someone could offer me a small and clean solution (without RegEx).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use regex? This is the sort of reason why it exists.

Comment: I have some other stringmanipulations in my application, they are all without regex.. Trying to hold some order.. But if theres no other way  I would use regex aswell..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following should work:

```
var result = new string(
    test.TakeWhile((c, index) => index == 0 || char.IsLower(c)).ToArray());
```

Comment: @abatishchev: yes but after you need to inject it *in front* of the result string for correct output. In *this* way it's more elegant **imo**-

Answer (score 1):

You could just go through the string to see which values (ASCII) are below 97 and remove the end. Not the prettiest or LINQiest way, but it works...

```
    string test2 = "CustomerNumberHello";

    for (int i = 1; i < test2.Length; i++)
    {
        if (test2[i] < 97)
        {
            test2 = test2.Remove(i, test2.Length - i);
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(test2); // Prints Customer
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 private static string GetFirstWord(string source)
        {
            return source.Substring(0, source.IndexOfAny("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToArray(), 1));
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

Z][a-z]+ regex it will split the string to string that start with big letters her is an example

```
  regex = "[A-Z][a-z]+";
            MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, regex);
            foreach (Match match in mc)
                if (!match.ToString().Equals(""))
                    Console.writln(match.ToString() + "\n");
```

Comment: From OP's post `hope someone could offer me a small and clean solution (without RegEx).`

Answer (score -3):

I have tested, this works:

```
string cust = "CustomerNumberHello";
string[] str = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(cust, @"[a-z]+");
string str2 = cust.Remove(cust.IndexOf(str[1], 1));
```

Comment: Well, an explanation as to why this has been down voted would be useful.

Comment: The OP specifically requested an answer without Regex.

Comment: Well, that went unnoticed. My bad.